# Grails databinding and allowed HTTP methods

Tags: grails, data-binding

I have the following action in a controller

```
class RegisterController {

    static allowedMethods = [register: 'POST']

    def register(User user) {
        // action body omitted
    }
}
```

If a user tries to invoke this action via `GET /register/register/newUser`, I get a databinding failure because `newUser` cannot be bound to the user's `Long id` property.

This seems reasonable at first, however IMO no attempt should ever be made to bind the `user` when it is invoked via HTTP GET, because I've declared that only POST is allowed.

Curiously, if I change the action to:

```
class RegisterController {

    static allowedMethods = [register: 'POST']

    def register() {
        User user = new User(params)
    }
}
```

and again try to invoke it with `GET /register/register/newUser`, then I get the expected HTTP method not allowed (405) error. It seems to me that databinding is happening before the HTTP request type is checked, and this is why I get a binding error in the first case and a 405 error in the second.

Shouldn't I get a 405 in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should get a 405 in both cases.  File a report at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS and we will get it straightened out.  We have an AST transformation which adds the command object handling code and adds the allowedMethods handling code.  It sounds like they may not be in the right order.  Will get it straightened out.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If you do file a JIRA please indicate which version of Grails you are using.  I just created a sample 2.4.2 app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/allowedmethodsproblem and the RegisterControllerSpec there indicates that a 405 is being returned when expected.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Note that with that 2.4.2 app the data binding is still happening before the 405 is sent, which should be improved, but the 405 is sent.  It sounds like in your case that isn't happening and I would like to pin down why that is.

Comment: I observed this issue in Grails 2.4.0

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/5dd77fdb393d344718ffabf562edb096b2db0d0d and https://github.com/grails/grails-functional-tests/commit/9f353a07f6458f4f8318bbda9d1369df2140f0e2.